# Where is the loop?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have this piece of code to create a typing carousel effect for my webpage. I'm trying to make it so that the carousel stops once it reaches the last string in the array. But I'm having trouble locating where the infinite loop is?

Since there's no while or for loop, I'm confused as to how this is even repeating. Could someone give me pointers?

```js
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
  return;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 80;

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    delta /= 2;
  }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 200;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  var toRotate = elements[0].getAttribute('data-rotate');
  var period = elements[0].getAttribute('data-period');
  if (toRotate) {
    new TxtRotate(elements[0], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
  return;
};
```

Comment: The "loop", such as it is, is enabled by `setTimeout` calling the function that called `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses some kind of clock that "rewinds" itself.

The end of `tick` is this :

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
```

It means that when the function `tick` ends, it schedules itself to be called again after `delta` time.

See [setTimeout documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) if you are not familiar with this (very useful) JavaScript function.

If you want to make it stop repeating itself, just wrap the above lines in an `if` block with your continuation condition, and you're good to go.

The very first call to `tick` happens when the object TxtRotate is created, in the constructor.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Is there a way to not call the next tick if a certain condition is met?

Comment: What schedules the next call is this `setTimeout`. Just wrap that call (the lines that I copied in the answer)  in some `if` block and you have your end condition!